# Bases for $\mathbb{F}_2$ and for $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we find three bases for $\mathbb{F}_2$ and for $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{F})$.
I tried but I couldnt think of anything. New to linear algebra course.

Comment: What exactly is $F$ supposed to be? Any field in particular?

Comment: yes any field. Nothing particular.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only two elements common to *every* field $\Bbb F$ are $0$ and $1$, so those are the only entries we can use here.

Here are $3$ bases of $\Bbb F^2$:
$$
\{(1,0),(0,1)\}\\
\{(1,0),(1,1)\}\\
\{(0,1),(1,1)\}\\
$$
Note that, depending on your book's definition, it is possible that rearranging the elements of a basis produces a new basis, in which case there would be $6$ possible answers to this part, as opposed to just the $3$ I gave.